# Show that $\{\max_{0 \le i \le n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \epsilon_j \ge t \}=\sqcup_{i=0}^{n} E_i$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n$ be $n$ i.i.d random variables taking the values $1$ and $-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. Suppose we look at the event $\{\max_{0 \le i \le n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \epsilon_j \ge t \}$. Can I write this event as a disjoint union of $E_i$'s where $E_i=\{ \sum_{j=1}^{i} \epsilon_j \ge t, \sum_{j=1}^{l} \epsilon_j < t , \forall l \le i-1\}$ ? That is I am claiming that $\{\max_{0 \le i \le n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \epsilon_j \ge t \}=\sqcup_{i=0}^{n} E_i$.

Note: $\sum_{j=1}^{0} \epsilon_j=0$. Here $t>0$.

Please help me how is this claim true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the least integer such that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N}\epsilon_j \geq t$. Then $E_i$ is nothing but the set $\{N=i\}$ and these are disjoint. Since $N$ takes then values $1$ to $n$ we see that $\{\max_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i}\epsilon_j \geq t\} =\bigcup_i E_i$.

Comment: Please read last paragraph of my post before closing, the same answer you mentioned is mentioned in the OP

Comment: Can you explain why are they disjoint?

Comment: The events $\{N=i\}$ are obviously disjoint, aren't they? @MathsFreak

Comment: Oh yes sorry! my bad

Comment: I understand that $\{N=i\}=E_i$. But how is the $\{\max_{0 \le i \le n} \sum_{j=1}^{i} \epsilon_j \ge t \}=\cup\{N=i\}$?

Comment: If the maximum of $c_0,c_1,...,c_n$ is $\geq t$ then there exists at least one $i$ such that $c_i \geq t$. And this implies that there is  a least interger $i$ such that $c_i \geq t$. @MathsFreak